# android - changing ListPreference value from an Activity

Tags: android, android-preferences

Following the new API's I have created a pretty simple `PreferenceFragment`:

```
  public class PrefsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
}

    }
```

I use that in my `Activity` created to enable the user to change app settings:

```
  public class SetPreferenceActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(android.R.id.content, new PrefsFragment()).commit();

}

   }
```

Now I need to change the summary of a `ListPreference` according to user's choice. There is no `findPreference()` method defined for `Activity` class, **so how can I access the desired preference?**

Sorry if the answer is obvious, I'm not really familiar with the new API and always used a `PreferenceActivity` before it became deprecated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing `new PrefsFragment()` right in your statement where you replace the fragment you can do this.

```
PreferenceFragment pFrag = new PrefsFragment();
PrefsFragment pf = (PrefsFragment)pFrag;

getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .replace(android.R.id.content, pFrag).commit();
```

then in your PreferenceFragment you create a public method that you can change what you want

```
pf.changeMyPreference();
```

Comment: Following your advise I tried to create such method in my PrefsFragment. That method finds the preference using findPreference() but its always null. The key is 100% correct. Any ideas?

Comment: well I figured out that this method gets called BEFORE addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences); so the preference cannot be found. Looking for a way around..

Comment: what method gets called before? are you trying to change the preference before it gets created or after the fragment was created where a value changed and you want something to display differently?

Comment: already figured it out. Accepting since you got me thinking the right way. I set the OnPreferenceChangeListener inside the Fragment itself and it works